# Using a python web crawler to scrape twitter accounts

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

I'm writing this program for my A-Level Computer Science coursework, and I am trying to get a crawler to scrape all the found users from a given users following/followed list.

The start of the script is as followed:

```
import requests
# import database as db
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

debug = True


def getStartNode():  # Get the Twitter profile of the starting node
    global startNodeFollowing  # Declare the nodes vars as global for use in external functions
    global startNodeFollowers
    global startNodeLink
    if not debug:  # If debugging == False, allow the user to enter any starting node Twitter profile
        startNodeLink = input("Enter a link to the starting users Twitter profile\n[URL]: ")[:-1]  # Get profile link, remove the last char from input (space char, needed to enter link in terminal)
    else:  # If debugging == True, have predetermined starting node to save time during development
        startNodeLink = ("https://twitter.com/ckjellberg03")
    startNodeFollowers = (startNodeLink + "/followers")  # Create a new var using the starting node's Twitter profile, append for followers and following URL pages
    startNodeFollowing = (startNodeLink + "/following")
```

And the crawler is here:

```
def spider():  # Web Crawler
    getStartNode()
    print("\nUsing:", startNodeLink)

    urlFollowers = startNodeFollowers
    sourceCode = requests.get(urlFollowers)
    plainText = sourceCode.text  # Source code of the URL (urlFollowers) in plain text format
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText,'lxml')  # BeautifulSoup object to search through plainText for specific items/classes etc
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l'}):  # 'a' is a link in HTML (anchor), class is the Twitter class for a profile
        href = link.get(href)
        print(href) # Display everything found (development purposes)
```

I'm pretty sure the class identifier for a users link to their Twitter profile from a /followers is "css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l" from looking at source code, but printing results displays nothing.

Any advice to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to scrape Twitter (trust me I have try every way), you can use Twitter API but they have limitation (you can't have the name of the followers only the number) if you want to scrape some information with Twitter API you can use this code:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI, TwitterPager
import tweepy
from tweepy import Cursor
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

consumer_key = 'consumer key'
consumer_secret = 'consumer secret'
token = 'token'
token_secret = 'token secret'

auth= tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(token, token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

account_list = ['POTUS44']



for target in account_list:
    print("Getting data for " + target)
    item = api.get_user(target)
    print("name: " + item.name)
    print("screen_name: " + item.screen_name)
    print("description: " + item.description)
    print("statuses_count: " + str(item.statuses_count))
    print("friends_count: " + str(item.friends_count))
    print("followers_count: " + str(item.followers_count))

    tweets = item.statuses_count
    account_created_date = item.created_at
    delta = datetime.utcnow() - account_created_date
    account_age_days = delta.days
    print("Account age (in days): " + str(account_age_days))
    if account_age_days > 0:
      print("Average tweets per day: " + "%.2f"%(float(tweets)/float(account_age_days)))

    tweets = item.statuses_count
    account_created_date = item.created_at
    delta = datetime.utcnow() - account_created_date
    account_age_days = delta.days
    print("Account age (in days): " + str(account_age_days))
    if account_age_days > 0:
      print("Average tweets per day: " + "%.2f"%(float(tweets)/float(account_age_days)))

    hashtags = []
    mentions = []
    tweet_count = 0
    end_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=30)
    for status in Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=target).items():
      tweet_count += 1
      if hasattr(status, "entities"):
        entities = status.entities
        if "hashtags" in entities:
          for ent in entities["hashtags"]:
            if ent is not None:
              if "text" in ent:
                hashtag = ent["text"]
                if hashtag is not None:
                  hashtags.append(hashtag)
        if "user_mentions" in entities:
          for ent in entities["user_mentions"]:
            if ent is not None:
              if "screen_name" in ent:
                name = ent["screen_name"]
                if name is not None:
                  mentions.append(name)
      if status.created_at < end_date:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it without API. Some difficulties stem from using the right
browser in User-Agent,

```
import re, requests

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'UCWEB/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +google.com/bot.html)'}


def cleanhtml(raw_html):
  cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
  cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
  return cleantext

content = ""
for user in ['billgates']:
    content += "============================\n\n"
    content += user + "\n\n"
    content += "============================\n\n"
    url_twitter = 'https://twitter.com/%s' % user
    resp = requests.get(url_twitter, headers=headers)  # Send request
    res = re.findall(r'<p class="TweetTextSize.*?tweet-text.*?>(.*?)</p>',resp.text)
    for x in res:
        x = cleanhtml(x)
        x = x.replace("&#39;","'")
        x = x.replace('&quot;','"')
        x = x.replace("&nbsp;"," ")
        content += x 
        content += "\n\n"
        content += "---"
        content += "\n\n"
```